# ASP.NET MVC Web Api reutilization

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Before there was "web api", one had to do actions of the type `JsonResult GetPersons(..)`. Now, with web api, one can have `List<Person> GetPersons(..)`.

I thought the whole point of this was to reutilize the actions, that is: call GetPersons from another action (maybe `ActionResult GetPersons(..)`).

But after many serialization problems I'm figuring out that this is not an option. For example, as simple as if the object has an enum inside, it can't be serializated to json.

So I ended up with many `dynamic X(...)` returning anonymous types and I cant really reuse many things of my API. Anny suggestions?

A example of a repeated code is the following:

Json:

`from a in b select new { ... }`

Not json

`from a in b`

Also, I've read in many forums that is not good to return the EF object itself, and thats exactly what web api motivates (and the existence of [ScriptIgnore])

The question: How do I reuse queries in the API and in the normal controllers?

Comment: In the grounds that it is not a question.

Comment: WebAPI does not "motivate" you to use EF or any other kinds of entities. The examples you see often do this because it's faster for MS to show it this way and because they want you to take a hard dependency on EF. However you do not have to return entity models. You can return ViewModels, EditModels, even specialized API-specific  models.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I reuse queries in the API and in the normal controllers?

By not defining the queries in your API or MVC controllers. You can define the queries in a shared assembly, external to the MVC project, and have the controllers call into that layer.

Example:

**Externalized**

```
public interface IQuery<TResult> {}

public interface IQueryProcessor
{
    TResult Execute<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
}

public class MyQueryObject : IQuery<MyEntity[]>
{
    public string QueryParam1 { get; set; }
    public int QueryParam2 { get; set; }
}
```

**API Controller**

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IQueryProcessor _queryProcessor;

    public MyApiController(IQueryProcessor queryProcessor)
    {
        _queryProcessor = queryProcessor
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyApiModel> Get
        ([FromUri] string queryParam1, int queryParam2)
    {
        var query = new MyQueryObject
        {
            QueryParam1 = queryParam1,
            QueryParam2 = queryParam2,
        };
        var results = _queryProcessor.Execute(query);
        return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyApiModel>>(results);
    }
}
```

**MVC Controller**

```
public class MyMvcController : Controller
{
    private readonly IQueryProcessor _queryProcessor;

    public MyMvcController(IQueryProcessor queryProcessor)
    {
        _queryProcessor = queryProcessor
    }

    public ViewResult Index(string queryParam1, int queryParam2)
    {
        var query = new MyQueryObject
        {
            QueryParam1 = queryParam1,
            QueryParam2 = queryParam2,
        };
        var results = _queryProcessor.Execute(query);
        var models = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyViewModel>>(results);
        return View(models);
    }
}
```